# Entity Framework Version Number

Tags: entity-framework, version

wanted to check my EF version number - Properties says 6.0.0.0, so I used the PM console to Install-Package EntityFramework & it (the PM Console) reports EntityFramework 6.1.2 already installed.

I'm using .Net framework 4.5 so I'm expecting no problems. Does EF in fact report the most current version under properties, or does it always say 6.0.0.0? Any advice?

Comment: Use `Get-Package` in the PM console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the file properties of EntityFramework.dll in Windows Explorer, and you will see a product version of 6.1.2 - the 6.0.0.0 version is the assembly version